# Why should I use a mocking framework instead of fakes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

There are some other variations of this question here at SO, but please read the entire question.

By just using fakes, we look at the constructor to see what kind of dependencies that a class have and then create fakes for them accordingly.

Then we write a test for a method by just looking at it's contract (method signature). If we can't figure out how to test the method by doing so, shouldn't we rather try to refactor the method (most likely break it up in smaller pieces) than to look inside it to figure our how we should test it? In other words, it also gives us a quality control by doing so.

Isn't mocks a bad thing since they require us to look inside the method that we are going to test? And therefore skip the whole "look at the signature as a critic".

**Update to answer the comment**

Say a stub then (just a dummy class providing the requested objects).

A framework like `Moq` makes sure that `Method A` gets called with the arguments `X` and `Y`. And to be able to setup those checks, one needs to look inside the tested method.

Isn't the important thing (the method contract) forgotten when setting up all those checks, as the focus is shifted from the method signature/contract to look inside the method and create the checks.

Isn't it better to try to test the method by just looking at the contract? After all, when we use the method we'll just look at the contract when using it. So it's quite important the it's contract is easy to follow and understand.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your concept of 'fake'. Mock is essentialy a fake. Could you elaborate more on 'than to look inside it to figure out how we should test it'? We need to know what's going on inside to test it nonetheless, else we don't know what to expect, what to test.

Comment: Ah, If we go by Martin Flower, there are Dummies, Fakes, Stubs and Mocks and all are different from one another.
Read this: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: The mock allows you to have more fine control over your assertions, while the stub only provides you data needed for your test. You can set up a stub to return X, but how would you know if that method got called at all? Mocking allows you to check that fact as well.

Comment: A more generic Term would be TEST DOUBLE

Comment: @Bartosz: Read my update

Comment: You seem to write the test AFTER the code... thus these questions come up... IF you wrote the test FIRST you wouldn't even have the possibility to look into the method... so I am not sure whether you question would even apply in that case (test first) which in IMO would be best practice...

Comment: Well, ideally it's good not to have to look inside the method, but we're not living in pure functional world, we're living in dangerous imperative world, in which most of your methods have side effects and you need to be aware of their existence, and maybe you would also like to test them.

Comment: @Yahia: How could I use mocks if I wrote the test first? There would be nothing to mock ;) At some point, I do need to look inside the method to be able to create the mocks.

Comment: @Bartosz: It should be easy to test functionality in well defined/written methods without looking in them. Just validate that the stub got the correct object (updated/deleted/removed or whatever).

Comment: you could even create a mock based on a stub or even a fake if you use a common interface... which could be well before the real code is written...

Comment: When your method uses functionality provided by some outside objects (given by their interfaces) it relies on a contract. Mocks allow you to check, whether that method understands the contract, by calling that interface methods in a proper way.

Comment: @Bartosz: If the contract of the dependency is unclear, it should be refactored and not validated.

Comment: Consider example in my answer, we've got method that use some interface `fileManager`. We might want to test that the method calls `saveDoc` method of this interface. This dependency is not so visible via signature, in this case your tests help also to make this dependency more clear, as people often read tests to understand code. How would you check it with stubs?

Comment: I would add a public property to my stub called SavedDocuments that is a list of all saved documents. It doesn't matter which of the methods in the dependency are called or the signature used. What matters are that a document are saved. Else you are also validating the dependency contract and not just the tested class.

Comment: But then I think you're essentialy copying the functionality of mocks (you will be filling SavedDocuments property in a method of your stub, a *particular* method), which would allow you to do the same check with smaller effort. Will your stub really remain stub then, or would it become to be  a mock?

Comment: I guess you are right. I don't really have to check that argument X and argument Y has the correct values when using mocking frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a grey area and I think that there is some overlap. On the whole I would say using mock objects is preferred by me.

I guess some of it depends on how you go about testing code - test or code first?

If you follow a test driven design plan with objects implementing interfaces then you effectively produce a mock object as you go.

Each test treats the tested object / method as a black box.

It focuses you onto writing simpler method code in that you know what answer you want.

But above all else it allows you to have runtime code that uses mock objects for unwritten areas of the code.

On the macro level it also allows for major areas of the code to be switched at runtime to use mock objects e.g. a mock data access layer rather than one with actual database access.

Answer (score 1):

Fakes are just stupid dummy objects. Mocks enable you to verify that the controlflow of the unit is correct (e.g. that it calls the correct functions with the expected arguments). Doing so is very often a good way to test things. An example is that a `saveProject()`-function probably want's to call something like `saveToProject()` on the objects to be saved. I consider doing this a lot better than saving the project to a temporary buffer, then loading it to verify that everything was fine (this tests more than it should - it also verifies that the `saveToProject()` implementation(s) are correct).

As of mocks vs stubs, I *usually* (not always) find that mocks provide clearer tests and (optionally) more fine-grained control over the expectations. Mocks can be too powerful though, allowing you to test an implementation to the level that changing implementation under test leaving the result unchanged, but the test failing.

Comment: I have used mocking frameworks. You are missing my point. I'm not asking why they are better regarding functionality. I'm asking if stubs aren't really better since they moved the focus from the tested method contents to the actual signature (which is what we'll used in our production code)

Answer (score 1):

By just looking on method/function signature you can test only the output, providing some input (stubs that are only able to feed you with needed data). While this is ok in some cases, sometimes you **do** need to test what's happening inside that method, you need to test whether it *behaves* correctly.

```
string readDoc(name, fileManager) { return fileManager.Read(name).ToString() }
```

You can directly test returned value here, so stub works just fine.

```
void saveDoc(doc, fileManager) { fileManager.Save(doc) }
```

here you would much rather like to test, whether method `Save` got called with proper arguments (`doc`). The doc content is not changing, the fileManager is not outputting anything. This is because the method that is tested depends on some other functionality provided by the *interface*. And, the interface is the contract, so you not only want to test whether your method gives correct results. You also test whether it uses provided contract in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I see it a little different. Let me explain my view:

I use a mocking framework. When I try to test a class, to ensure it will work as intended, I have to test all the situations may happening. When my class under test uses other classes, I have to ensure in certain test situation that a special exceptions is raised by a used class or a certain return value, and so on... This is hardly to simulate with the real implementations of those classes, so I have to write fakes of them. But I think that in the case I use fakes, tests are not so easy to understand. In my tests I use MOQ-Framework and have the setup for the mocks in my test method. In case I have to analyse my testmethod, I can easy see how the mocks are configured and have not to switch to the coding of the fakes to understand the test.

Hope that helps you finding your answer ...